# How can I get list of users to display in Inbox ordered by the recent person sent the message

Tags: php, sql

I've got this table by the name `messages` which contains the sender id and receiver id

What I want to do is fetch all the users I am supposed to display in the inbox list.
based on the timestamp received or sent a message in that conversation with the current user id given

**[Here's my fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c1efYKLp4KS9PYNRfocj9M/1)**

This is what I tried so far which isn't working as required

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE message_type = 'individual' AND sent_by = 1 GROUP BY receiver_ids 

UNION 

SELECT * FROM messages WHERE message_type = 'individual' AND receiver_ids = 1 GROUP BY sent_by
```

I want the records to be grouped by user id based on sent or received messages and ordered in timestamp descending order

Here's how the expected final output should look like, when the user viewing the records have `user_id 1`

| user_id | message | sent_on |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Message number 2 testing | 2021-12-28 08:42:33 |
| 2 | Message number 2 testing | 2021-12-28 08:42:33 |

Comment: Please write your expected output for the example above.

Comment: if it's going to be inbox of a user then you should create another table which is conversations with sender, receiver and conversation_id. You create 1 conversation when user_A send msg to user_B and after save the conversation_id back to every message between them. Then you can get conversations of a user and join the messages to get the last message. Thats how i do it in my social network.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you - [mcve].

Comment: @JonArmstrong yes it does, in fact, your answer was quite working perfectly for me.. is it possible to add the last message as well along with it?

Comment: @fra yes your solution seems easy to implement, I was actually trying not to create too many DB tables

Comment: @groovy_guy you have to pre-plan. Sometines better to have multiple tables for speed. I have 70k users and the messages table usually around 300K lines. Much easier to filter it by index and just by conversations what i am actually looking for than write complex and slow querie to filter the whole lot. Also in that way you can add more features like delete conversation from one but not from other user...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please have look.

```
SELECT sent_by,
    message,
    sent_on
    FROM   (SELECT *
    FROM   messages
    WHERE  message_type = 'individual'
        AND sent_by = 1
        GROUP  BY receiver_ids
        UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM   messages
    WHERE  message_type = 'individual'
        AND receiver_ids = 1
        GROUP  BY sent_by) t
    ORDER  BY sent_on DESC;
```